# Confusion on NaN in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, double, nan

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
double nan1 = (double)0/0;
double nan2 = (double)0/0;
double nan3 = (double)i/j;
System.out.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan1) == Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan2));
System.out.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan1) == Double.doubleToRawLongBits((double)0/0));
System.out.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan3) == Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan2));
```

output:

```
true
true
false
```

Please help me how the output came `true` for first two and `false` for last one. Please tell me what is actual work of **Double.doubleToRawLongBits()** method.

Comment: There are two different `NaN`s being produced. One is `0x7ff8000000000000` and the other is `0xfff8000000000000`. The hardware seems to give `0xfff8000000000000` for `0 / 0`. But the compiler's constant propagation is using `0x7ff8000000000000` instead. Unless I overlooked something, this looks like a bug to me.

Comment: What if you enable `strictfp` for the method?

Comment: Besides: »In IEEE 754 standard-conforming floating point storage formats, NaNs are identified by specific, pre-defined bit patterns unique to NaNs. The sign bit does not matter.« ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Encoding))

Comment: Can you clarify what you are confused about?  Is it a question of why NaN can have different bit patterns, or why the bit pattern produced is different between two cases involving the same values?

Comment: @DanielPryden I think you understood my actual confusion. My doubt is why the third print statement gives false, though both nan3 and nan2 are generated with same numbers i.e. by doing 0/0. Please answer me, I am not cleared with the answers already given.

Answer (score 3):

Please try to run following code to see the values:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        double nan1 = (double)0/0;
        double nan2 = (double)0/0;
        double nan3 = (double)i/j;
        System.out.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan1) + " == "+ Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan2) + " is " +
            (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan1) == Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan2)));
        System.out.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan1) + " == "+ Double.doubleToRawLongBits((double)0/0) + " is " +
            (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan1) == Double.doubleToRawLongBits((double)0/0)));
        System.out.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan3) + " == "+ Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan2) + " is " +
            (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan3) == Double.doubleToRawLongBits(nan2)));
    }
}
```

On my Mac, it produces following output:

```
9221120237041090560 == 9221120237041090560 is true
9221120237041090560 == 9221120237041090560 is true
-2251799813685248 == 9221120237041090560 is false
```

This pitfall is documented in the Javadoc for the [doubleToRawLongBits method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29):

> If the argument is NaN, the result is the long integer representing the actual NaN value. Unlike the doubleToLongBits method, doubleToRawLongBits does not collapse all the bit patterns encoding a NaN to a single "canonical" NaN value.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: The code is the same as in the question so fairly superfluous; but following the link to the docs *does* answer the question, albeit with one indirection. I edited the relevant part in as a quote. But I'd say that everything above that is just junk that has nothing to do with an answer.

Comment: ah. Okay then. I should delete this answer. :)

Comment: Undeleted, as I think currently it answers better (with Joey's edit) than other answers.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because when you divide a double variable 0 by 0 it returns NaN, so the method doesnt have a single canonical representation in binary, so it may return the binary of NaN as 7F F8 00 00 00 00 00 00 or FF F8 00 00 00 00 00 00.

Even though technically they represent the same thing, which is NaN, its different in binary representation.

Answer (score 2):

The IEEE 754 standard allows different bit patterns for `NaN`. For computation and comparison purposes they should all work the same (i.e. `NaN` compares not equal to itself, is not ordered and every computation involving `NaN` is `NaN` itself). With `doubleToRawLongBits` you get the exact bit pattern used. This is also detailed in the JLS:

> For the most part, the Java platform treats NaN values of a given type as
>   though collapsed into a single canonical value (and hence this specification nor-
>   mally refers to an arbitrary NaN as though to a canonical value). However, version
>   1.3 the Java platform introduced methods enabling the programmer to distinguish
>   between NaN values: the `Float.floatToRawIntBits` and `Double.double-
>   ToRawLongBits` methods. The interested reader is referred to the specifications
>   for the `Float` and `Double` classes for more information.

In your case the sign bit is different, in this case I can direct you to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Encoding), which summarises this concisely:

> In IEEE 754 standard-conforming floating point storage formats, NaNs are identified by specific, pre-defined bit patterns unique to NaNs. The sign bit does not matter.

Both your values are `NaN`, they just use different bits to represent that. Something that is allows by IEEE 754 and in this case probably stems from the compiler substituting `Double.NaN` for a constant computation that results in `NaN` while the actual hardware gives a different result, as suspected by [Mysticial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008755/confusion-on-nan-in-java#comment14387877_11008755) in a comment to the question already.

Comment: Joey is compiler chooses different bit patterns randomly for NaN values. If no, then why same pattern for nan1 and nan2 but different pattern for nan3.

Answer (score 1):

I think Java follows IEEE 754. In this case NaN has more than one possible bit representation. The two representations in your case differ in the "sign" bit. The value of the sign bit seems to be not defined by the standard and is usually ignored. So both values are correct. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN